# "IF" statements in a process do not work properly

Tags: vhdl

My VHDL code doesn't do what I need it to do. 
I have an incoming 8-bit code that I need to grab by the "button" "reset", then I need to return the number of rhe first "1" there is in this code. for this I am copying it into sub sequence and pushing it until there is a "1" in the end.

but "q" doesn't stop incrementing some how... 
What is wrong?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity count is
    port
    (
        clk : in std_logic;
        reset   : in std_logic;
        start   : in std_logic;     
        q       : out integer range 0 to 7;
        sequence : in bit_vector (0 to 7)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of count is

signal sub_seq : bit_vector (0 to 7);

begin
    process (clk)
        variable   cnt  : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            if reset = '1' then
                sub_seq <= sequence;
            end if;
        end if;     

        if reset = '1' then
                cnt := 0;
                sub_seq <= sequence;
        end if;

        if ((reset = '0') and (sub_seq(0) = '0')) then
                cnt := cnt + 1;
                sub_seq <= sub_seq sra 1;
        end if;

        if (start = '0') then
                cnt := cnt + 1;
                sub_seq <= sub_seq sra 1;
        end if;
    q <= cnt;
    end process;

end rtl;
```

Comment: You mean, it doesn't work *as you expect*. Note that only part of your process is controlled by `rising_edge(clk)` -- the rest is just free-running combinatorial logic, generally a Bad Idea.

Comment: if you want synchronous resets, put all of the subsequent code (removing redundancies that will be created) inside the `if-then-else` block for `rising_edge(clk)`.  If you want asynchronous resets put an `if-then-else` for your reset, followed by a `if-then-else` for `rising_edge(clk)`.  Good practice: Anything being updated/assigned on the clock edge, should be assigned on reset too.  check sensitivity list for any not assigned on clk (e.g. reset if asynchronously applied).  Also, try not to mix combinatorial and sequential in the same process block (except for asynch reset of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made all the logic synchronous. this way it works.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity count is
    port
    (
        clk : in std_logic;
        reset   : in bit;
        start   : in std_logic;     
        q       : out integer range 0 to 7;
        sequence : in std_logic_vector (0 to 7)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of count is

signal sub_seq : std_logic_vector (0 to 7);

begin
    process (clk, reset, start, sequence)
        variable   cnt  : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            if reset = '1' then
                sub_seq <= sequence;
                cnt := 0;
            end if;

            if (((reset = '0') and (sub_seq(7) = '0'))) then
                cnt := cnt + 1;
                sub_seq <= '0' & sub_seq (0 to 6);
            end if;     

            if ((start = '1') and (sub_seq(7) = '1')) then
                cnt := cnt + 1;
                sub_seq <= '0' & sub_seq (0 to 6);
            end if;

        end if;     


    q <= cnt;
    end process;

end rtl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Took this from [allaboutfpga.com](https://allaboutfpga.com/synchronous-asynchronous-reset-vhdl/), you do not need "data" in the sensitivity list, and for synchronous reset, you do not need "reset" in the sensitivity list.

**Asynchronous reset:**

```
process(clock,Reset,data)
  if Reset = '1' then
    q <= '0';
  elsif Rising_edge(clock) then
    q <= data;
  end if;
end process;
```

**Synchronous reset:**

```
process(clock,Reset,data)
  if Rising_edge(clock) then
    if Reset = '0' then
      q <= '0';
    else
      q <= data;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: You got your labels exactly backwards. The first one is asynchronous and the second one is synchronous. Also, the first is active-high reset, while the second is active-low, which just muddles matters.

Comment: 10-4, sure is... edited it.. sorry, @RKishmar if this confused the issue.  Stupid labels :/

Comment: The code for synchronous reset on allaboutfpga.com has a mistake. The reset signal is still in the sensitivity list, however you stated the opposite (which is correct).

Comment: Yeh, I probably should have taken more time, and just typed it, or copy-pasted a better example, instead of leaving it and making the statement.  It's not wrong to have it in the sensitivity list, it just isn't needed, and can be misleading in terms of the intent of the designer.

Answer (score 0):

What you designed is an asynchronous design. You do have a `process` with the `clk` signal in its sensitivity list, that's okay and you even have an if statement to check for the `rising_edge(clk)`, so far so good. But you should put everything that is logic inside this if statement except a dedicated reset (not your button input). In fact in your case

```
if (rising_edge(clk)) the
    if reset = '1' then
        sub_seq <= sequence;
    end if;
end if;
```

Does not have a special effect because you do the same assignment asynchroneously as well when you do

```
    if reset = '1' then
            cnt := 0;
            sub_seq <= sequence;
    end if;
```

Is `sequence` a static value? I'm not hundred percent sure if I got you right but your code should rather look something like this.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity count is
port
(
    clk : in std_logic;
    reset   : in std_logic; --use this as an actual reset to have a defined initial state, generated by the FPGA
    button : in std_logic; -- this is your button input
    start   : in std_logic;     
    q       : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- try to use std_logic wherever possible
    sequence : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
);
end entity;

architecture rtl of count is

signal sub_seq : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); --use std_logic_vector
signal button_new, button_old : std_logic;
signal   cnt  : unsigned(7 downto 0);
begin
main_process : process (reset, clk) -- giving the process a name helps to read and understand the code
begin
    if reset = '1' then
        sub_seq <= (OTHERS => '0'); -- initialize the vector
        button_new <= '0';
        button_old <= '0';
        cnt <= to_unsigned(0, cnt'LENGTH);
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        button_new <= button;
        button_old <= button_new;
        if button_old = '0' AND button_new = '1' then -- only sample on the rising edge of the button input
            sub_seq <= sequence;
            cnt <= to_unsigned(0, cnt'LENGTH);
        elsif (sub_seq(0) = '0') then
           sub_seq <= sub_seq(0) & sub_seq(sub_seq'LEFT downto 1);
           cnt <= cnt+1; --be careful with variables, would suggest to use std_logic_vector.
        else 
            q <= cnt;
        end if;
    end if;     
end process;

end rtl;
```

Comment: cnt <= cnt + 1; returns an error due to it's non-numeric std_logic type. went to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854684/why-cant-i-increment-this-std-logic-vector?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa and used "cnt <= std_logic_vector( unsigned(cnt) + 1 );". Compilation OK, need some time to test carefully.

Comment: Ah sorry, you can change the type to unsigned so you don't have to "cast" it... made the changes in the code

Comment: the counter is counting as the clock is ticking, the "sequence" does not copy to "sub_seq". (p.s. change "v" to "c" in logiv_vector))

Comment: Sorry, the assignment for button_new was missing...
Of course the whole thing has some potential for improvement, you could inhibit your counter once you found the leading '1' or wait for the button press before you start shifting. This should rather be some guideline to overcome your initial issue than a complete solution for your problem :)